# We are the first inhabitants

Tags: riddle, rhyme

We are the ancients, though we still sit among you.

We have many forms, and even more layers

No strangers to pressure, we use it to shine through

We'll hold you up while you kneel for your prayers

We have patience beyond compare

We'll crack and break and never whine

But when we fight, you'll know we're there

Especially if you toe the line

---

What is our name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are the

> Tectonic Plates

We are the ancients, though we still sit among you.

> Plate tectonics probably started on Earth over 3 billion years ago, currently there are seven recognised plates.

We have many forms, and even more layers

> Wikipedia gives an extensive [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tectonic_plates) of plates. Processes like subduction mean the plates occupy several layers of the lithosphere.

No strangers to pressure, we use it to shine through

> The plates often move and cause areas of pressure in the Earth's crust. This can be the cause of diamond formation.

We'll hold you up while you kneel for your prayers

> We live on top of tectonic plates.

We have patience beyond compare

> The plates are very slow moving in general, typically from 0 to 100mm per year.

We'll crack and break and never whine 
But when we fight, you'll know we're there

> A clashing of plates at a convergent boundary can cause earthquakes.

Especially if you toe the line

> Toeing the line means being near a plate boundary.

Comment: Hmm I was going for "rocks" but I guess they all fit the more specific instance. Nicely done!